# Autocomplete like Outlook using typeahead and Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, typeahead

I want to create a textbox that utlise the typeahead Autocomplete of ui-angular, I want that the autocomlementation works every time I type the key ";"for example: 
when I type "anny" in the textbox all contact email address containing "anny" appears, I select the one I want and when I type the key ";" I can again use autocomlementation.(like Outlook)... I have already created a textbox but it only works for an email address

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':NewRequest.BeneficiaryId.$invalid}">
     <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-lg-2 control-label"> Email:</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="text" name="BeneficiaryId" 
                ng-model="Ticket.BeneficiaryId" placeholder="Email" 
                typeahead="address as address.Email for address in Form.autoComplete($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue" 
                typeahead-loading=" loadinglocations" 
                class="form-control" required>

         <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"> </i>
     </div>
```

And that's my service for autocomplete

```
services.service('Form', function ($http, $q, $modal) {
this.autoComplete = function (val) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get("../api/Employee/getAutocomplet", {
        params: {sSearch: val }
    }).then(function (response) {

        var addresses = [];
        angular.forEach(response.data, function (item) {
            addresses.push(item);
        });
        deferred.resolve(addresses);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS typeahead + multi select tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22693325/angularjs-typeahead-multi-select-tags)

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is sometimes called "inline multiselect with typeahead". Popular non-Angular implementations include [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) and [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#multi). To understand how various implementations work I recommend viewing its source and inspecting the DOM elements.

I've been meaning to finish my [post here](https://github.com/rayshan/rayshan.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2013-08-10-how-inline-multiselect-works-build-the-angularjs-way.md), which details how this works and how to implement it in AngularJS. The gist is:

- Bind keyboard strokes to selecting the item, e.g. `enter`, `tab` or `;` in your case
- Push the item into an array of selected items
- `ngRepeat` the array and render as inline list to the left of `input`, which pushes `input` over
- Clear `input` content and keeping focus within it, this allows you to keep typing for more

You can this Angular [implementation here](https://github.com/rayshan/ui-multiselect) and [demo here](https://apps.shan.io/ui-multiselect/demo.html).

[image: ui-multiselect]

Comment: Thank you !! this is very similar but how can I do to load my data because they are not fixed (as many data) how can I tell him that data = address as address for address.email in FormField.autoCompletePerson ($viewValue) | filter: $viewValue

Comment: Regarding data, the list of email addresses may not be fixed, but the data structure should be. If you're fetching and filtering out of a database, that logic should be in a service, then controller should assign the emails into an object. When template is compiled, the email object's structure should not change. But the way your html template is written is hard to understand without the larger context. Are you using a vendor module? What does `typeahead` attribute do? How are you displaying the list of emails?