# AngularJS typeahead + multi select tags

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, multi-select, typeahead

What I'm looking for is a input that resembles Gmails typeahead for email addresses

[image]

Challenges:

1) It should display both the Name EmailAddress and Image (Basically a customizable template)

2) It should display the Name of the contact added to the list

3) It should work with backspace to remove the previous entry

4) It should work with select and , to add the new etnry

Comment: As a slight aside; the angular directive you linked previously (https://github.com/Siyfion/angular-typeahead) will support all of what you are asking for, as standard. Full disclosure: I'm the author.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
.directive('typeahead', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        scope: {
            model: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function link($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.$watch('inputValue', function (value) {
                $scope.changed();
            });

            $scope.Emails = ['a@a.com', 'b@b.com', 'c@c.com'];

            $element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
                switch (event.keyCode) {
                    case 40:
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            if ($scope.selected < $scope.List.length) {
                                $scope.selected++;
                            }
                        });
                        event.preventDefault();
                        break;
                    case 38:
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            if ($scope.selected > 0) {
                                $scope.selected--;
                            }
                        });
                        event.preventDefault();
                        break;
                    case 13:
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            $scope.selectAndClose($scope.List[$scope.selected]);
                        });
                        event.preventDefault();
                        break;
                    case 32:
                    case 188:
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            inputValues = $scope.inputValue.split(',');
                            for (var i = 0; i < inputValues.length; i++) {
                                if (inputValues[i].length > 0) {
                                    $scope.GetOrCreateEmailAndSelect(inputValues[i]);
                                }
                            }
                            $scope.clear();
                            $scope.close();
                        });
                        event.preventDefault();
                        break;
                    case 27:
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            $scope.close();
                        });
                        event.preventDefault();
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            if ($scope.inputValue == null || $scope.inputValue.length == 0) {
                                $scope.model.pop();
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                }
            });

            $scope.remove = function (emailid) {
                $scope.model.splice($scope.model.indexOf(emailid), 1);
            }

            $scope.changed = function () {
                fetchEmail({
                    'EmailAddress__icontains': $scope.inputValue
                }).then(function (data) {
                    $scope.List = data;
                    if (typeof ($scope.model) === typeof ([]) && $scope.model !== null) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.model.length; i++) {
                            for (var j = 0; j < $scope.List.length; j++) {
                                if ($scope.List[j].id == $scope.model[i].id) {
                                    $scope.List.splice(j, 1);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $scope.selected = 0;
                    dropdownShow = false;
                    if ($scope.List.length > 0) {
                        if (typeof ($scope.inputValue) !== 'undefined' && $scope.inputValue !== null) {
                            if ($scope.inputValue.length > 1) {
                                dropdownShow = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $scope.dropdownShow = dropdownShow;
                });
            };

            $scope.selectAndClose = function (value) {
                $scope.select(value);
                $scope.clear();
                $scope.close();
            };

            $scope.select = function (value) {
                $scope.model.push(value);
            };
            $scope.clear = function () {
                $scope.inputValue = null;
            };
            $scope.close = function () {
                $scope.dropdownShow = false;
            };
            $scope.GetOrCreateEmailAndSelect = function (EmailAddress) {
                EmailAddress = EmailAddress.toString();
                data = $scope.fetchEmail(EmailAddress); //you can add an ajax call here
                if (data.length == 0) {
                    $scope.CreateEmail(EmailAddress);
                } else {
                    $scope.select(data[0]);
                }
            });

        $scope.fetchEmail =function(EmailAddress) {
            result = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Emails.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.Emails[i].indexOf(EmailAddress) > -1) {
                    result.push($scope.Emails[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        $scope.CreateEmail =function(EmailAddress) {
            $scope.Emails.push(EmailAddress);
        };
    }
    $scope.mouseoverChoice = function (emailidobject) {
        $scope.selected = $scope.List.indexOf(emailidobject);
    };
    $scope.editEmailId = function (emailidobject) {
        $scope.inputValue = emailidobject.EmailAddress;
        $scope.remove(emailidobject);
    }
    $scope.CheckSelected = function (element) {
        if (typeof ($scope.List) !== 'undefined' && typeof ($scope.selected) !== 'undefined' && typeof ($scope.List[$scope.selected]) !== 'undefined') {
            return $scope.List[$scope.selected].id == element.id;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
},
    templateUrl: 'typeaheadtemplate.html',
}
});
```

Comment: Have you tried Angular-UI's Typehead with custom templates?

Comment: Hey I have, but it doesn't support all of the functionality I am talking about. Especially not the custom key methods and not the tags. I would need to fork it and make extensive changes.

Comment: @sj7, don't know if this was a working example, but plkr gave a lot of errors, now I cleaned those out, but still trying to figure out how the setup should be to get this working.

this is what I have so far: http://plnkr.co/edit/0Nm4Wf?p=preview

Comment: @Kiwi, your right it wasn't a working example. I actually had used it in one of my projects and didn't take the time to make it run independently. Let me take a crack it it sometime this week. Will try to make it run independently.

Comment: @sj7, Thanks a lot, but I found another directive, so you don't have to do it for me :)

Comment: @kiwi could you post the link here

Comment: @sj7 this is the plugin I used: http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput but a lot of tweaking on CSS part is needed :p

Comment: @sj7 Hi can you please send me the fiddle link for this.?